# how to use a method only if its an instanceof in java

Tags: java

Please check the code bellow and tell me what to do
I am trying to use the method howToColor only for GeometricObjects subclasses that implement the interface (Colorable)

```
    //GeometricObjects is an abstract class
    GeometricObjects[] array = new GeometricObjects[5];
    array[0]= new Triangle(4.0, 3.0, 5.0);
    array[1]= new Square(6.3);
    //continue for all elements...


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] instanceof Colorable)
            array[i].howToColor;
```

this doesn't work because GeometricObjects doesn't implement Colorable
is there a way i can do this

I hope I made it clear enogh

p.s:I'm new here :).

Answer (score 7):

Use a cast (which is known to not throw `ClassCastException` because of the `instanceof` check)

```
if(array[i] instanceof Colorable)
        ((Colorable) array[i]).howToColor;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does it